# Populate vector of vectors from input file?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to populate a vector of vectors from an input file.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("input.dat");

    if(!inputFile){
            cout << "Error in reading" << "input" << endl;
            return 0;
    }

    vector<vector<double> > A;
    double element;
    vector<double> temp;

    while(inputFile << element){
            temp.push_back(element);
            A.push_back(temp);
    }

    int len = A.size();
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
            for(j=0; j<len; j++){
                    cout << A[i] <<"\n";
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using this as a test file, so I am trying to print the matrix A. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
test.cpp:33:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are 
‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::vector<double>’)
cout << A[i] <<"\n";
```

Comment: inputFile should be `ifstream`. You are missing another index when you are using A, it should be `A[i][j]`

Answer (score 0):

Change the while loop to this:

```
while(inputFile >> element){
        temp.push_back(element);
        A.push_back(temp);
}
```

And in the nested for loop do `cout<<A[i][j]<<endl;`

Comment: After changing the operator I am getting this error:

 24:18: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}’ and ‘double’)
  while(inputFile >> element){

Comment: @RamziSaud Could you change ofstream to ifstream which overloads that operator